# ios uidatepicker with presentModalViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, show, uidatepicker, presentmodalviewcontroller

I need to show a view with a uidatepicker inside..
I tried with presentModalViewcontroller, but shows correctly my new viewcontroller with the uidatepicker, but cover all the iphone, and I wish that the uidatepicker will be shown on the bottom part of the screen...

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a modal view controller for that—the picker is a single view, and should be part of the view hierarchy of whatever view controller it's supposed to be editing something in. Just position it so it's off the screen to the bottom, then animate it in (look up `UIView` animations in the docs) to a position onscreen when you need it.